# Is there a way to add mixins to the usage of <body /> inside a component

Tags: tapestry

Consider a component say `Article` used in a `tml` file as follows:

```
<t:article id="id">
    <t:contols model="articleControls" />
</t:article>
```

The `tml` of the `Article` component is say as follows:

```
<article class="app-some-wrapper-class">
  <h2>${title}</h2>
  <h3>${subtile}</h3>
  <body t:mixins="decorator" decorator="shadow" /> <!-- note the use of a mixin here -->
</article>
```

I need to apply the mixin to the `<body/>` parameter, but this implementation will throw an `ApplicationExpection`. What is the correct way or alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body t:type="any" t:mixins="decorator" decorator="shadow" />
```

upd: refer to t5 doc about any:
https://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Any.html

Comment: Please explain your answer, code only answers might fix the problem but don't explain the problem/solution why would this work?

Comment: Yes, an explanation would be helpful. Why adding `t:type="any"` makes it work. I will also test it out in the meanwhile.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

xl0e's answer works, because you can only apply a mixin to a tapestry compoent (identified by tags that begin with t:)  is simply a HTML tag, not a tapestry component. To apply your mixin to it, you convert it to a tapestry component by adding the t:any attribute.

It might be clearer if the code was written as `<t:any element="body" t:mixins="decorator" >...</t:any>`